# Cobertura code coverage results not complete

Tags: java, hudson, jenkins, cobertura

I am using Cobertura for code coverage analysis. If I run a build in Jenkins the classes in `generated` are contained in the coverage result but the coverage is at *0%*. If I run code coverage in my workspace (Eclipse) the coverage is much higher. The coverage for the package `com.my.package` is ok. Have I missed some configuration?

My projects structure is as following:

```
- com
+- com.my
+-- com.my.package
+--- class1.java
+--- class2.java
- generated
+- classX.java
+- classY.java
```

My cobertura configuration in the POM-file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
                <check>
                    <branchRate>0</branchRate>
                    <lineRate>0</lineRate>
                    <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
                    <totalBranchRate>0</totalBranchRate>
                    <totalLineRate>0</totalLineRate>
                    <packageLineRate>0</packageLineRate>
                    <packageBranchRate>0</packageBranchRate>
                </check>
                <instrumentation>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Test.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </instrumentation>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, but wasn't satisfied with the 'don't do code coverage on generated code' answer. I managed to put together the following [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159656/cobertura-code-coverage-for-freemarker-auto-generated-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated code should not be tested and should not be used in code coverage metrics. The reason is that you should not be testing the library that is generating the code.

I've never used Cobertura myself, but it seems that you should add something like this:

```
            <instrumentation>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Test.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>generated/*.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </instrumentation>
```